# How to redirect from model

Tags: magento2, php, model, redirect

I want to do redirect after do function from model. I already tried both code below, both works redirect, but both return error too.

Redirect 1 :

```
$this->_redirect('*/*/addresses');
```

Redirect 2 :

```
$resultRedirect = $this->resultRedirectFactory->create();
return $resultRedirect->setPath('*/*/addresses');
```

Is there another way to redirect from model without returning error?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No worries!
We also can redirect from Model.

Just try the following code in your model:

Add below code as parameter in `__construct` method of your Model

```
\Magento\Framework\UrlInterface $url, 
\Magento\Framework\App\ResponseFactory $responseFactory,
```

Then next, Create object for both as below

```
$this->_url = $url;
$this->_responseFactory = $responseFactory;
```

Now whatever your method in this model, use following code to redirect

```
$CustomRedirectionUrl = $this->_url->getUrl('REDIRECTION URL HERE');
$this->_responseFactory->create()->setRedirect($CustomRedirectionUrl)->sendResponse();
exit();
```

Don't Forgot to put `exit` at the end!

Cheers!!!

Comment: It's works, thank you!!! :) but you should change '$this->request = $request;' to '$this->_responseFactory = $responseFactory;' but still, thank you for your answer!!! :)

Comment: Yes @user58086 Sorry! I have updated the answer. :)

Comment: But, Is this correct using exit(); function?